# GPU has two 8-pin PCIe sockets for power and my PSU has only one PCIe 6+2 connector. Is that one cable sufficient?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, pci-express

I'm building a PC and I've got an issue with the GPU ([Sapphire Pulse 7800 XT 16gb graphics card](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/pulse-radeon-rx-7800-xt-16g-gddr6)) and the Deepcool DQ850-M-V3L 850 W modular power supply I'm using.

The main problem is that the GPU has two 8-pin PCIe sockets for power and my PSU has only one PCIe 6+2 connector. I want know if that one cable is sufficient or do I have to use a PSU that has 2 PCIe 6+2 connectors. I'm a bit confused

Comment: If the PSU is model number PQ850M then it should have come with 3 PCI-E(6+2)Pin leads, according to the [Deepcool product page](https://www.deepcool.com/products/PowerSupplyUnits/powersupplyunits/PQ850M-80-PLUS-Gold-Modular-Power-Supply/2021/14032.shtml). You would need to use 2 of them for that graphics card. If the PSU is a [DQ850-M-V2L](https://www.deepcool.com/products/PowerSupplyUnits/powersupplyunits/DQ850-M-V2L-80-Plus-Gold-Power-Supply/2021/32.shtml) then it comes with 2, which is still enough. Maybe you need to check the leads for another one you didn't see the first time.

Comment: The psu is DQ850-M-V3L

Comment: Ah, if that's the Indian-market version then it looks like that model only comes with one PCI-E cable. Which is a bit mean of them, especially as they don't appear to sell extra cables. You have to be very careful with PSU cables because there is no standard for which way the PSU end is connected. I know it's always fun to assemble a PC as soon as you've got the parts, but is there any chance you could return that one and get a different PSU which comes with enough cables? (Seasonic is a good brand, IME.)

Answer (score 0):

The 7800 XT has a TDP of 263 W, requiring two 8-pin power connectors.

The Deepcool 850W PSUs that @AndrewMorton linked to have at least 6+2 connectors. If you've lost one of the modular cables you'll need to get a replacement.

Alternatively, an adapter from 2x Molex 4-pin to 8-pin PCIe could work but you should make sure that the Molex lead isn't fed from the same 12V rail as the first PCIe power connector you've got (which can be tricky). [...] Looking at the product photos, it seems that both models only use a single 12V rail, so an adapter should work either way.

[image]

Comment: It appears that, for some markets, the OP's PSU is supplied with only one graphics card power lead :(